# Using <select multiple> to populated text field in PDF

Tags: html, xml, pdf, xml-parsing, pdf-generation

I have 3 files: and html file, a XML file, and a PDF form. I have the PDF auto populating from the data entered into the html via the XML code. I need to have a drop down menu where I can select multiple items and have them auto populate into a text field in the PDF form. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks I'll have to try that and see

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, if you are using a listbox with the multiple selections flag set (as opposed to a combobox, which allows for single selections only).

Most likely in the target (multiline) text field you evaluate the `currentValueIndices` property of the listbox, and use the indices you get from there to read out the values via the `getItemAt()` method. Those, you can write into your text field.

See also Acrobat JavaScript documentation.